# Sending very big amount with sendtoaddress RPC call

Tags: json-rpc, php

I am working with Infinitecoin (another bitcoin fork).
This is my first attempt to make a crypto currency based website.
I use PHP with JSON RPC calls.
In this particular case, I want to use

```
$payment_tx = $ifc->sendtoaddress($account['address'], $to_send);
```

($ifc is the object returned by the jsonRPcclient() connection)

`sendtoaddress()` description states :

*$amount is a real and is rounded to 8 decimal places.*
So I formatted "$to_send" as precised in the description, but i'm still getting  :

*Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/process_payment.php(30): jsonRPCClient->__call('sendtoaddress', Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/process_payment.php(30): jsonRPCClient->sendtoaddress('iKCBBVAfacVuabG...', '10920.00000000') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/jsonRPCClient.php on line 140*

I really don't understand why, because I intend to send exactly 10920 Infinitecoins to the address starting with iKCBBVAfacVuabG ... and this is formatted the right way, right?
I also want to be able to send IFC amounts up to several millions. How ?

Here's how I do the formatting :

```
$to_send = sprintf("%.8f", floatval($amount));
```

$amount is retrieved from a database.

Please can somebody enlighten me with what am I doing wrong ?

I can offer some IFC as a thank for your help, if someone want some. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to send amount as string. Sprintf returns string.
You need to send amount as double (in PHP double == float).
Try this way:

`$payment_tx = $ifc->sendtoaddress($account['address'], (double)$to_send);`

If it doesn't work, use move at first, because sending can fail under many circumstances, while move always works.

Once you are done with that, please read my question about further problems with precision: [Can I force json_encode in PHP to output 8 digits after dot for RPC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12392/can-i-force-json-encode-in-php-to-output-8-digits-after-dot-for-rpc)